# Изменения в тексте статей Wordpress видны только в админке

Tags: wordpress

Редактирую текст в Wordpress, затем сохраняю. Но изменения в тексте появляются только тогда, когда я захожу под админом, у обычных пользователей изменения не видны. Не думаю, что текст тоже кэшируются. В первые с таким сталкиваюсь. Как исправить?

Comment: Когда вы заходите в админку, кэш отключается. А при просмотре страницы пользователем, который не залогинен, ему отдается не результат обработки .php-файла, а сохраненный .html. Так работает WP Super Cache и аналогичные плагины или средства кэширования.

Comment: @KAGGDesign вообще-то в админке тоже [могут быть проблемы из-за Pragma](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85/#post-244839), но к данному вопросу это не имеет никакого отношения. Просто для инфы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не думаю, что текст тоже кэшируются.

А подумать стоит. 99% что это кеш.

Так же обратить внимание на состояние поста - опубликован ли он или черновик или запланирован.

Comment: Прошу прощения действительно стоял плагин но не знал что текст может кэшироваться.

Comment: @ДарханУрустимов если проблема решена стоит отметить её решённой. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers